# Passing more than three parameter to route in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I got an error "Missing required parameters for Route" although I used a correct. Who can support me, please?

```php
    Route::Group(['prefix' => 'shop'], function () {
    Route::get('product_page/orderby/{pa1}/rangeform/{pa2}/rangeto/{pa3}/type/{pa4}', ['as' => 'product_page', 'uses' => 'shopcontroller@product_page']);
    });
```

```php
    public function product_page($orderby,$rangeForm,$rangeTo,$type){
           // do something
    }
```

```
   <a href="{{ route('product_page',['orderby'=>'1','rangeto'=>'50000','rangeform'=>'500000','type'=>'1']) }}"><img src="/source/images/p1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
```

> "Missing required parameters for [Route: product_page] [URI: shop/product_page/orderby/{pa1}/rangeform/{pa2}/rangeto/{pa3}/type/{pa4}]. (View: E:\shopmarket\resources\views\shop\product.blade.php)"

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name in function should be same as in url {var}

```
public function product_page($pa1,$pa2,$pa3,$pa4){
   // do something
```

Answer (score -1):

The params in your route and your function should match (either names and number of params). In your case, you have 8 params -instead of 4-, the `product_page` function should look like:

```
public function product_page($orderby,$rangeform,$rangeto,$type){
       // do something
}
```

and change the Get Router like (with optional params):

```
Route::get('product_page/{orderby?}/{rangeform?}/{rangeto?}/{type?}', ...
});
```

Also make sure when you buld your URL that your resulting URL is build according, it should be:

> /product_page?order_by=1&rangeform=50000&rangeto=50000&type=1

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you JP, i tried to use your way but it's doesn't work

Comment: Which is the resulting URL of: {{ route('product_page',['orderby'=>'1','rangeto'=>'50000','rangeform'=>'500000','type'=>'1']) ? Maybe it should be: {{ route('shop/product_page',['orderby'=>'1','rangeto'=>'50000','rangeform'=>'500000','type'=>'1']) with the /shop/ parameter as it has the `prefix` = shop?

Comment: yes is right. I have tried the following ways. I have tried code below:
 <a href="{{ route('shop/product_page',['orderby'=>'1','rangeForm'=>'50000','rangeTo'=>'500000','type'=>'1']) }}"><img src="/source/images/p1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
 Its result is "Route [shop/product_page] not defined. (View: E:\shopmarket\resources\views\shop\index.blade.php)"

Comment: when i use three parameter, it nothing problem and work ok. But when add four parameter, it's occur to error

Comment: Thanks JP, it worked ok with this code 
 Route::Group(['prefix' => 'shop'], function () {
Route::get('product_page/{orderby?}/{rangeForm?}/{rangeTo?}/{type?}', ['as' => 'product_page', 'uses' => 'shopcontroller@product_page']);
 });

Comment: Your welcome! I updated the answer to help others too. Happy coding!